# AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'Pub_Date' не работает PubDate

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-model

вот код из моделей приложения:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone

class Article(models.Model):
    Articles_title = models.CharField('название статьи',max_length = 200)
    Articles_text = models.TextField('текст статьи',max_length = 500)
    Pub_Date = models.DateTimeField('дата публикации')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.Pub_Date>=(timezone.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Articles_title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Articles_text
        
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    Author_name = models.CharField('имя автора',max_length = 50)
    Comment_text = models.TextField('текст комментария',max_length = 500)
```

вот ошибка:

```
>>> a.was_published_recently()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Django\mysite\mysite\apps\articles\models.py", line 12, in was_published_recently
    return self.PubDate>=(timezone.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1))
AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'Pub_Date'
```

Comment: Ну да, совершенно очевидно, что в модели Article не существует никакого Pub_Date. В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: я исправил, но ошмбка осталась

Comment: ты имеешь ввиду как отдельная модель class или что-то другое?

Comment: 'я исправил, но ошмбка осталась'... а миграции сделали заново и джангу перезапустили?

Comment: да, уже пробовал

Answer (score -1):

```
makemigrations appname
```

```
migrate
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]